# XMLHttpRequest not working in cordova 3.3

Tags: cordova

I am using web service(SOAP) to consume data from external source,

I am able to getting the response using eclipse web browser, but not working in Android device and simulator(i am getting 0 as response)

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://hmecd000910/ClubdService/ClubDSecurityService.svc', true);

var sr = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">'+
'<soapenv:Header/>'+
'<soapenv:Body>'+
   '<tem:GetUserByUserEmail>'+      
      '<tem:userEmail>nc@usl.com</tem:userEmail>'+
   '</tem:GetUserByUserEmail>'+
'</soapenv:Body>'+
'</soapenv:Envelope>';

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {         
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         alert(xmlhttp.status+'--'+xmlhttp.readyState);
     if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {           
         alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }     
    // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
}

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-length',sr.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://tempuri.org/IUSLClubDSecurityService/GetUserByUserEmail');

xmlhttp.send(sr);
```

I have configured the config.xml in the following way,

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try with below code

```
$.post( ipAddress +"/acb.php", { user_id:userID,password:pwd} , function( data ) {
                                                                if(data.status==true){
                                                                         //response 
                                                                }
                                                              },"json");
```